# Custom Views model

Tags: android, view

I'm beginner now moving from tutorial to developing a real android app..
Any idea on how to convert this excel sheet to a custom view the easy way?
the section# and items# and field# are fixed.
the month must reflect table length and I want the user with a single click to fill/unfill with 'X' table cells and count them.

[image: costum sheet from excel]

thanks

Comment: Can you show us some of your own research ?

Comment: I will use library for month-year picker and I a list view + header and the child items a TextViews x nbr month days  but not sure how to align with month days